# How to query pending server-call actions made from Lightning Controller?

Tags: lightning, query, actionsupport

I've been searching through the documentation but I couldn't find anything explaining how to query pending server-call actions made from my lightning component controller.
I can debug using the browser's dev console and I see that my event is been fired.
The problem I'm facing is that since this is an asynchronous process, we can't guarantee the order in which they will be processed, which is totally fine and is not a problem at all, but some of them are taking "forever" to "return"...

Is there any documentation out there I could refer to, or maybe if you guys know a query I could run to see the pending ones I would really appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightning actions are placed in a queue and are executed during the Aura life cycle. If you call $A.enqueueAction outside of the life cycle, they will remain pending until the next life cycle (e.g. an event is fired). You should only use $A.enqueueAction directly in response to an event, or use $A.getCallback to ensure you start a new life cycle. This is the most usual reason why you'd have actions pending that never seem to fire, is because they are added outside the life cycle.

## Will Misbehave

```
method1: function(c,e,h) {
  // setTimeout means the function will be called outside Aura life cycle
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      var action = c.get("c.serverCall");
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }, 0);
}
```

---

## Will Execute Correctly

```
method1: function(c,e,h) {
  setTimeout(
    // getCallback makes sure that we are in a life cycle!
    $A.getCallback(
    function() {
      var action = c.get("c.serverCall");
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }), 0);
}
```

---

As far as checking the queue? No. You can't check the queue, there's no API for that, and the actions/internals are protected by the framework. All you can do is make sure you're always queuing the actions within the Aura life cycle.